# not sure why object is local vs reference

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, reference

I am pretty sure I'm retrieving a reference to a `Flashcard` object that is in scope but IDE is telling me that `entry` is a local object..

```
const ::std::pair<int64, Flashcard>& GetCardHandler::GetRandomFlashcard() {
  const ::std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard>& flashcards_ = Get<FlashcardContext>()->GetFlashcardMap();
  const ::std::pair<int64, Flashcard>& entry  = *( std::next(std::begin(flashcards_), rand_between(0, flashcards_.size()) ) ); ;
  return entry;
}
```

More context (from `FlashcardContext` class)...

```
const ::std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard>& GetFlashcardMap();
...
std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard> flashcards_ GUARDED_BY(lock_);
```

`Flashcard`s in this map are persistent due to internal framework.

Comment: What is the signature of `Get<FlashcardContext>()`? On a side note, `::std` looks extremely weird.

Comment: Your posted code looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value_type` of a `std::unordered_map` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. Notice the `const`?  It is missing in your declarations.

In your case, the `*iterator` returns a `std::pair<const int64, Flashcard>&`, which you are then saving to a `std::pair<int64, Flashcard>&`, so the compiler has to make a *temporary* `std::pair` object that is local to `GetRandomFlashcard()`, which you then `return` a reference to.  That is what the compiler is warning you about.

You need to update your declarations of `std::pair` to include the `const`:

```cpp
const ::std::pair<const int64, Flashcard>& GetCardHandler::GetRandomFlashcard()
{
    const ::std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard>& flashcards_ = Get<FlashcardContext>()->GetFlashcardMap();

    const ::std::pair<const int64, Flashcard>& entry = *( std::next(std::begin(flashcards_), rand_between(0, flashcards_.size()) ) );
    // alternatively:
    // const ::std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard>::value_type& entry = ...;

    return entry;
}
```

Though, you really should make use of `auto` to simplify your declarations:

```cpp
// pre-C++14
const ::std::pair<const int64, Flashcard>& GetCardHandler::GetRandomFlashcard()
{
    const auto &flashcards_ = Get<FlashcardContext>()->GetFlashcardMap();
    const auto &entry = *( std::next(std::begin(flashcards_), rand_between(0, flashcards_.size()) ) );
    return entry;
}
```

```cpp
// C++14 and later
const auto & GetCardHandler::GetRandomFlashcard()
{
    const auto &flashcards_ = Get<FlashcardContext>()->GetFlashcardMap();
    const auto &entry = *( std::next(std::begin(flashcards_), rand_between(0, flashcards_.size()) ) );
    return entry;
}
```

Or, at least use some `using` statements to simplify your usage of templates:

```cpp
using FlashcardMap = ::std::unordered_map<int64, Flashcard>;
using FlashcardMapEntry = FlashcardMap::value_type;

...

const FlashcardMap& GetFlashcardMap();
...
FlashcardMap flashcards_ GUARDED_BY(lock_);

...

const FlashcardMapEntry& GetCardHandler::GetRandomFlashcard()
{
    const FlashcardMap& flashcards_ = Get<FlashcardContext>()->GetFlashcardMap();
    const FlashcardMapEntry& entry = *( std::next(std::begin(flashcards_), rand_between(0, flashcards_.size()) ) );
    return entry;
}
```